# Using Linq to select subset from a Dictionary<string, int>?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm newer to `C#` and I'm trying to use LINQ (or another method?) to select a subset of a `Dictionary<string, int>` object where the value (`int`) is greater than 5.

```
+-------------+------------+
| Key(string) | Value(int) |
+-------------+------------+
|         000 |          0 |
|         111 |          1 |
|         222 |          2 |
|         333 |          3 |
|         444 |          4 |
|         555 |          5 |
|         666 |          6 |
|         777 |          7 |
|         888 |          8 |
|         999 |          9 |
+-------------+------------+
```

I created the dictionary object above with this code to simply fill a dictionary with some data:

```
        Dictionary<string, int> linkCounter = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
        {
            string key = i.ToString() + i.ToString() + i.ToString();
            for (int n=0; n<=i; n++)
            {
                if (linkCounter.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    linkCounter[key]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    linkCounter.Add(key, 0);
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I do something equivalent to:

> `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in linkCounter` **[where kvp.value > 5]**`)`

Comment: Did you try calling `.Where()`?

Comment: No. No idea that exists or how to use it? I've read about it, but I can't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
using System.Linq;
```

and then use [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var subset = linkCounter.Where(x => x.Value > 5);
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in subset)
{
   // your code
}
```

Comment: When I use `var` it works, but the way you edited/wrote now I'm getting `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: However if I do this `foreach(KeyValuePair<string,int> kvp in linkCounter.Where(x => x.Value > 5))` it works. What would be the proper way to cast the first line the way you wrote it? I can't accept the answer for another few minutes or I would have already marked it.

Comment: The declaration of `subset` is wrong. `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which in this case would be `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`

Answer (score 1):

```
var subset = linkCounter
    .Where(w => w.Value > 5)
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Like mentioned in the answer above, what Linq returns is an `IEnumerable<kvp<K,V>>` when you operate on a dictionary. If you want to get a dictionary back you can use the method I used in the method above to convert the Enumerable back to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var keyValueSet = linkCounter.Where(p => p.Value > 5);
keyValueSet.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Key + ": " + i.Value));
```